# PostGIS generate lanes for multilinestring map (ST_OffsetCurve)

Tags: postgis, cartography, road, offset

I currently have a road network for specific area as multilinestrings. It only shows the road as a single line. I would like to generate lanes for that as well, using some kind of offset. The problem is that ST_OffsetCurve only generates some weird curved shapes. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

```
SELECT St_offsetcurve(thegeom, 2, 'quad_segs=4 join=round') AS 
  theoffset 
FROM   ( 
          SELECT (St_Dump(the_geom)).geom as thegeom 
            FROM   public.roadmap 
           WHERE  land='SP' 
             AND ST_IsValid(the_geom)) AS subquery
```

Gives me something like this:

[image]

Comment: I think you might need to provide a bit more information thatn some weird curved shapes. A code sample and/or a screen shot would be a good starting point..

Comment: how weird? add some more detail about what you did (query) and what you got (screenshot). and don't use *MultiLineStrings*

Comment: @ThingumaBob, well, England got further in a world cup than Germany, and Trump and May are somehow still in power, so the world is in kind of a weird state.

Comment: @ThingumaBob and John Powell aka Barça Added some information.

Comment: ah, well that is most likely due to the *distance* value; that value is taken in units of the data's SRID, e.g. *degrees* for EPSG:4326! if 2 meter is what you have in mind, but your data is in a geographic CRS, you'll need to transform the geometries into a projection with meter as unit.

Comment: That is somewhat weird it has to be said. I believe in your query you are missing an AND before ST_IsValid. I think you might have to post a couple of sample linestrings to figure out what is going on.

Comment: @ThingumaBob. That is a very good intuition. I wouldn't have thought of that.

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça ...relieving to know that, in PostGIS, weirdness usually is your own fault. easier to eliminate bugs in functions than presidents. or useless soccer billionairs.

Comment: @ThingumaBob. Ha, ha, ha, yeah, if only they open sourced the presidency.